# emacs starts in extremely tiny window

Tags: frames, start-up, frame-parameters

Emacs has been starting up in an extremely small window for some reason. The text size is normal, but the window is something like 3 lines tall x 10 chars wide. Of course I can use my mouse and just resize the window, after which it works totally fine.

I'm using Fedora 38 with Emacs 28.2 installed from dnf (Fedora's package manager). Desktop environment is "Gnome (not classic) with X11". I have nearly zero customizations, except I've hidden the scroll bar, tool bar, and menu bar using the M-` menu. Both my `default-frame-alist` and `initial-frame-alist` just has a single `vertical-scroll-bars = nil`, though there's a second line that says "CHANGED outside Customize", but I think that refers to the M-` menu being not part of the "customize" feature?

Fedora comes with Gnome with Wayland by default, but I switched it to X11 using the "cog" menu in login, and I *think* but am not 100% that this issue only started happening to me after the switch (on Wayland, I *think* it was not happening). When I do `ls ~ -a` I don't see any `.Xresources` or `.Xdefaults`.

What's going on?

edit: I tried opening emacs multiple times in a row, and *sometimes* it opens in a normal-sized window. Maybe half the time. I also tried doing `emacs -Q` and `emacs -q` and the issue does not happen: I just get an ordinary-sized window.

for reference, here is my ~/.emacs file (comments omitted for brevity):

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(custom-enabled-themes '(wheatgrass))
 '(make-backup-files nil)
 '(menu-bar-mode nil)
 '(ring-bell-function 'ignore)
 '(scroll-bar-mode nil)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:family "Noto Sans Mono" :foundry "GOOG" :slant normal :weight normal :height 139 :width normal)))))
```

Comment: Maybe check `site-lisp.el`? Do you see the frame-size problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file), and you then evaluate your customizations?

Comment: I updated the question. I'm not sure where site-lisp.el is

Comment: `emacs -Q` starts Emacs without `site-lisp.el` or your init file. `emacs -q` starts Emacs without (only) your init file.

Comment: Did the problem start suddenly or has it always existed with your current Emacs build? What's your Emacs version and platform (OS, window mgr)? Bisect your init file, to see which part of it seems to be allowing/causing the problem.

Comment: seems to always have happened. OS is Fedora 38, desktop environment is "Gnome (not classic) X11"

Comment: I put the info in the question before I made my previous comment 1 hour ago

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameSize

Comment: yes, I'm aware of frame sizes. That doesn't explain why I'm seeing this problem, especially since my .emacs (included in the question) doesn't say anything about frame sizes

Comment: I've reported this as an Emacs bug at https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=67654. I found that I could trigger it consistently from emacs -Q if menu-bar-mode is disabled. Maybe you could see if the reproduction steps work for you too?

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your Emacs' configuration file (located at ~/.emacs.d/init.el), it should maximize any new frame open :

```lisp
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
```

Or if you want any new frame to be a specific size, you can add this to your Emacs' configuration file :

```lisp
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 80))  ; Width set to 80 characters
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height . 24)) ; Height set to 24 lines
```

Bonus : you can replace "width" by "pixel-witdh" and "height" by "pixel-height" in the two previous lines to give the width and height in pixels instead of number of characters and lines.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem with emacsclient. I have Gnome keyboard shortcuts to open certain buffers, and after some upgrade Emacs was opening in a tiny window. To workaround it I'm calling emacsclient with the following argument:

```
emacsclient -c --eval "(set-frame-size (selected-frame) 106 41)"
```

Thanks g-gundam for pointing:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameSize

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Started happening to me recently as well (recent debian, wayland, gnome). Super annoying.

I added this to .emacs to fix it:

```
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
          (lambda (frame)
            (run-with-timer 0.3 nil
                            (lambda (frame) (set-frame-size frame 80 100))
                            frame
                            )
            ))
```

This will also maximize the frame vertically, while keeping the width to 80.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing similar problems and posted my experience on https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=67654 but no progress on this, it's frustrating.
the workaround that works for me is `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))` but I'm not happy with it since I don't want my window maximized, just regular sized.
also, just like OP, this bug occurs roughly half the time; does everyone see these error messages when it does occur:

```
(emacs:5868): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 11:15:55.869: gtk_distribute_natural_allocation: assertion 'extra_space >= 0' failed
```

(repeated twice)?